# Showing two cardinalities are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra

The title is vague because im not sure what to call this problem:

Verify:

$|AN|$=$\frac{|A||N|}{|A \cap N|}$

for N a normal subgroup or G and A an arbitrary subgroup.

I think I can probably use Lagranges theorem and show the number of left cosets are equal, but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the second isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Hmm..Im not sure where to start (My book calls it the diamond theorem). Im just not sure how this theorem can indicate the order of a group (say AN)  I see it says that AN is isomorphic to A/(A$\cap$N) but what does this tell me abouts AN's order?

Answer (score 0):

The Second Isomorphism Theorem says that $AN/N\cong A/A\cap N$. Therefore, the order of both sides is the same. Now use the fact that if $G$ is a finite group and $N\lhd G$, then $|G/N| =|G|/|N|$.